# Memory Management issue while parsing the server data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I am working on one application, in that app i am fetching 20 web services sequentially and store that parsed data into sqlite. When i am checking the use of memory, then it will be used near to 100 MB. Is it harmful to my app?? Please check this screenshot, i am taken from allocator.
[image]

Here i am using the XML parsing Delegate code, Please check this and let me know if there any issue,

## pragma mark <-------------------- NSXMLParser Delegates -------------------->

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSMutableString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
            item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            self.section   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.position    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.title    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.auther    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.snippet    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.description    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.pubdate    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.category    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.guide    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.source    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            self.enclosure    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                
            self.enclosureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.enclosureUrlASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.enclosureTitleASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.enclosureDescriptionASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.enclosureTypeASrray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            self.enclosureLenghtASrray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            allocate=@"YES";
        }        
             
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
        {
                self.enclosureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.enclosureUrlASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.enclosureTitleASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.enclosureDescriptionASrray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.enclosureTypeASrray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.enclosureLenghtASrray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure_details"])
        {
                self.enclosureDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                self.enclosureUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                self.enclosureTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                self.enclosureDescription = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                self.enclosureType  = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                self.enclosureLenght  = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure_url"])
        {
                [self.enclosureUrl appendString:string];
        }
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure_title"])
        {
                [self.enclosureTitle appendString:string];
        }
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure_description"])
        {
                [self.enclosureDescription appendString:string];
        }
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure_type"])
        {
                [self.enclosureType appendString:string];
        }
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"enclosure_length"])
        {
                [self.enclosureLenght appendString:string];
        }

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"section"])
                [self.section appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"position"])
                [self.position appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"])
                [self.title appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"author"])
                [self.auther appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"])
                [self.link appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"snippet"])
                [self.snippet appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"description"])
                [self.description appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
                [self.pubdate appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"category"])
                [self.category appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"guid"])
                [self.guide appendString:string];
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"source"])
                [self.source appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        if ([allocate isEqualToString:@"YES"])
        {
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"section"])
                {
                        [item setObject:[self.section uppercaseString] forKey:@"articleSection"];
                }
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"position"])
                        [item setObject:self.position forKey:@"articlePosition"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
                {
                        [item setObject:MainCategoryID forKey:@"category"];
                        [item setObject:[self.title convertStringToHTML] forKey:@"articleTitle"];
                }
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"author"])
                        [item setObject:self.auther forKey:@"articleAuthor"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
                        [item setObject:self.link forKey:@"articleLink"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"snippet"])
                        [item setObject:[self.snippet convertStringToHTML] forKey:@"articleSnippet"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
                        [item setObject:self.description forKey:@"articleDescription"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
                        [item setObject:self.pubdate forKey:@"articlePubDate"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
                        [item setObject:self.category forKey:@"articleCategory"];
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"])
                        [item setObject:self.guide forKey:@"articleGuide"];
                
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure_details"])
                {
                        [self.enclosureUrlASrray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.enclosureUrl,SPECIAL_CHAR]];
                        
                        [self.enclosureTitleASrray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.enclosureTitle,SPECIAL_CHAR]];
                        
                        [self.enclosureDescriptionASrray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.enclosureDescription,SPECIAL_CHAR]];
                        
                        [self.enclosureTypeASrray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.enclosureType,SPECIAL_CHAR]];
                        
                        [self.enclosureLenghtASrray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.enclosureLenght,SPECIAL_CHAR]];
                }
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"])
                {
                        [item setObject:self.enclosureUrlASrray forKey:@"url"];
                        [item setObject:self.enclosureTitleASrray forKey:@"title"];
                        [item setObject:self.enclosureDescriptionASrray forKey:@"description"];
                        [item setObject:self.enclosureTypeASrray forKey:@"type"];
                        [item setObject:self.enclosureLenghtASrray forKey:@"lenght"];
                }
                
                if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
                {
                        [self.responseArray addObject:[item copy]];
                        self.section=nil;self.position=nil;self.title=nil;self.auther=nil;self.link=nil;self.snippet=nil;self.description=nil;self.pubdate=nil;self.category=nil;self.guide=nil;
                        self.source=nil;self.enclosure=nil;
                        self.enclosureUrl=nil;self.enclosureTitle=nil,self.enclosureDescription=nil,self.enclosureType=nil,self.enclosureLenght=nil;
                        self.enclosureUrlASrray=nil;
                        self.enclosureTitleASrray=nil;
                        self.enclosureDescriptionASrray=nil;
                        self.enclosureUrlASrray=nil;
                        self.enclosureLenghtASrray=nil;
                        item=nil;
                }
        }
        
}

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
    {
            NSLog(@"error : %@",parseError);
            [newHUD setHidden:YES];
            newHUD=nil;
                    //        [self noInternetMessage];
            if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ConnectionMessage:)])
            {
                    [_delegate ConnectionMessage:@"Error Occured When user Download  the Data From Server, Please Click Refresh Button."];
            }
    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
    {
            [newHUD setHidden:YES];
            newHUD=nil;
    //        NSLog(@"content Parsing : %@",responseArray);
            if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedResultBOArray:responseStr:)])
            {
                    [_delegate receivedResultBOArray:self.responseArray responseStr:MainCategoryID];
                    self.section=nil;self.position=nil;self.title=nil;self.auther=nil;self.link=nil;self.snippet=nil;self.description=nil;self.pubdate=nil;self.category=nil;self.guide=nil;
                    self.source=nil;self.enclosure=nil;
                    self.enclosureUrl=nil;self.enclosureTitle=nil,self.enclosureDescription=nil,self.enclosureType=nil,self.enclosureLenght=nil;
                    self.enclosureUrlASrray=nil;
                    self.enclosureTitleASrray=nil;
                    self.enclosureDescriptionASrray=nil;
                    self.enclosureUrlASrray=nil;
                    self.enclosureLenghtASrray=nil;
                    self.responseArray=nil;
            }
    }
```

Comment: How big is the XML? What are you doing with SQLite?

Comment: I suggest you to put `@autoreleasepool` at the beginning of each method. And what are you doing wiht `Sqlite` ??

Comment: did you try pressing cmnd+shift+b to see leaks?

Comment: As per client requirement, we want to store data and user can read the data when internet is off. That's why i am fetching all data when app is launch. Is there any other way to reduce that code..... ???

Comment: try braking it up in smaller methods and use autoreleasepools

Comment: Yeah if you have data then why not save that data in sqlite rather than xml ??? Convert your xml into sqlite using the same code above and then take your sqlite from doc dir and copy it into your resource and use that sqlite and comment your parsing code

Comment: also use if else instead of if only

Comment: Now its 75 MB... I implement all object with ARC enable...